# ¿Por que no consigo la transformación correcta de monedas con tres propiedades solo de lectura y otras tres para las transformaciones? C#

Tags: c#, calculo

Estoy realizando un ejercicio que consta de hacer una calculadora medieval, he de tener una variable coins, tres propiedades solo de lectura y otras tres publicas (long) para obtener la transformación en base a 10 de cobre = 1 plata, 100 cobre = 1 oro y 10 plata = 1 oro. Mi problema es saber que operación esta mal ejecutada o cual me faltaría.

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program instance = new Program();
            instance.Conversion();
            instance.Suma();
            instance.Resta();
        }

        public long coins;
        public long c, s, g;

        public long Copper
        {
            get { return (long)c - (g * 100) - (s * 10); }
        }
        public long Silver
        {
            get { return (long)s - (g * 10) + (c / 10); }
        }
        public long Gold
        {
            get { return (long)g + (c / 100) + (s / 10); }
        }

        public double result;
        public void Conversion()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Introduce la cantidad de monedas total: ");
            coins = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            c = coins;

            Console.WriteLine("Monedas //cobre = " + Copper + "// plata = " + Silver + "// oro: " + Gold);

        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Esta imagen seria la solución que me saca
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Y esta es la correcta solución

Comment: Que lenguaje es? Ademas, el codigo va como texto. Te recomiendo leer [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Gracias la recomendación y disculpa las molestias, espero que ahora este mejor formulado. Y el lenguaje seria C#. @JuanRivera.

Comment: No entiendo el enfoque. Cuando solicitas una cantidad de monedas se supone que pueden ser cualquiera o todas oro, o todas plata o mezcladas... ¿Ahora pregunto te refieres a un valor (que no número de monedas) y pretendes saber las monedas necesarias para alcanzar dicho valor?

Answer (score 0):

El cálculo está mal, primero:

```
public long coins;
public long c, s, g;
```

Las monedas deben ser números naturales, pues en numismática una fracción de moneda no existe: media moneda de plata es chatarra no cinco monedas de cobre. Segundo:

```
public long c, s, g;

public long Copper
{
    get { return (long)c - (g * 100) - (s * 10); }
}
public long Silver
{
    get { return (long)s - (g * 10) + (c / 10); }
}
public long Gold
{
    get { return (long)g + (c / 100) + (s / 10); }
}
```

¿Para qué transformas a `long` un dato que **ya es `long`**? Tercero: Si la equivalencia es de 10 en 10:

|  | Cobre | Plata | Oro |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cobre | x | 10 | 100 |
| Plata | 10 | x | 10 |
| Oro | 100 | 10 | x |

Simplemente usa módulo:

```
int coins = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int oro = coins / 100;
int cobre = coins % 10;
int plata = (coins % 100) - cobre;
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BSsQwEIbPzVMMi0J72FqPUjx5VVj04EE8jOlQBtqMZrILS8iz17TdrphTwvf980@s7q14mqajsuvh7ayBxtbYAVXh4KX3OEI0hQYMbOEk3MELsis1@Bz4@AT0vVamyE7BLoAVdgqPkO/1Ab1S@SROZaD6lbB7ZkdlVbUXWbxkdY3cwX3TtNcpX56u6DajjXwPGDCT8g81FezXRGuytfW9ew60FN7s4mInGMVRhwodXSro58gnHMgBQszr/FPm9eJSmObnWn2GuETTOqHezb9JJk3Tw3bMLw)</kbd>.